# Can't map route to action mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to create a new `Route` in MVC3 to achieve the link `http://localhost/Product/1/abcxyz`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "ProductIndex", // Route name
                "{controller}/{id}/{name}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

And I used `Route Link` like this:

```
<li>@Html.RouteLink("My Link", "ProductIndex", new { controller = "Product", id = 10, name = "abcxyz" })</li>
```

Product Index action:

```
public ViewResult Index(int id, string name)
        {
            var product = db.Product.Include(t => t.SubCategory).Where(s => s.SubID == id);
            return View(product.ToList());
        }
```

The url render as I expected. But when I click on it, I got a 404 error with message

```
HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly
```

**UPDATE**

I place that `Route` above `Default Route` and the URL work fine. But there's a problem occure. My index page `http://locahost` point directly to `Index` action of `Product` controller, but I want it points to `Index` action of `Home` controller instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have 2 optional parameters in your route and the engine can't work out which one to set the value to. See my answer to a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16625803/1859009)

You can create a specific route for your products controller first (with mandatory id) and then have the generic fallback route afterwards.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "ProductIndex", // Route name
            "products/{id}/{name}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", name = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Comment: Very nice, Sir. You save me a day.

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{id}/{name}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

for routing details see this link. In this link every type of routing is discussed.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/408227/Routing-in-MVC3

Comment: This will apply for all route. But I just want it apply for `Index` action of `Product` controller only.

Comment: @Atish Dipongkor Thanks for your attention, I found a solution as leveInis answer above